# LinkedIn Ads REST Api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am a developer and have recently been involved in developing an app that uses APIs from Google, Facebook, etc for publishing ads in their respective platforms. I had gone through the list of exposed API's for LinkedIn and couldn't find one that was relevant for my needs. On that note, I would like to know if LinkedIn has any REST API (or somewhere where I can get it from) for the service that I require for my ad publishing app.

Hoping for a positive reply. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn is SUPER stingy about their API access, and restrict it to only a few partners. Your best bet is AdStage.io - they're an API partner to all 5 search/social networks, and they offer a read-only API (no writing as far as I know, which may limit your ability to build your intended tool). The product is cheap - like $200/mo.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually we are looking for a such kind of reply what you have mentioned. We already know that AdStage is your api partner. But we are also be your api partner. Please mention the procedure.